# Unity always freezing after I added this while loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making game where players guessing letters from secretary. When I am generating letters options from which player can choose one option, I need to check if letter is not in scene already or if player used letter already. Everything works good until I added this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < button4b_value.Length;)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int randomNum = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, fourPointsLetters.Length);
            string currentRandomString = fourPointsLetters[randomNum];
            if (!usedLetters.Contains(currentRandomString))
            {
                if (!button4b_value.Contains(currentRandomString))
                {
                    button4b_value[i] = currentRandomString;
                    i++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else break;
        }
    }
```

Its impossible that `button4_value` contains all the `fourPointsLetters` items so this is not problem. I added `else` too (its not what I want, but just for test), but it still freezing. Any idea why this can freeze Unity? Or how to solve it?

Other code associated with this part:

**1. Set up values(pick random value from list to buttons):**

```
 private void SetUpPyramidButtonsValues()
    {
        selectedButton_value = null;
        string currentRandomFivePointString = fivePointsLetters[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, fivePointsLetters.Length)];
        if (!usedLetters.Contains(currentRandomFivePointString))
        {
            button5b_value = currentRandomFivePointString;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < button4b_value.Length;)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int randomNum = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, fourPointsLetters.Length);
                string currentRandomString = fourPointsLetters[randomNum];
                if (!usedLetters.Contains(currentRandomString))
                {
                    if (!button4b_value.Contains(currentRandomString))
                    {
                        button4b_value[i] = currentRandomString;
                        i++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else break;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < button3b_value.Length;)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int randomNum = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, threePointsLetters.Length);
                string currentRandomString = threePointsLetters[randomNum];
                if (!usedLetters.Contains(currentRandomString))
                {
                    if (!button3b_value.Contains(currentRandomString))
                    {
                        button3b_value[i] = currentRandomString;
                        i++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < button2b_value.Length;)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int randomNum = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, twoPointsLetters.Length);
                string currentRandomString = twoPointsLetters[randomNum];
                if (!usedLetters.Contains(currentRandomString))
                {
                    if (!button2b_value.Contains(currentRandomString))
                    {
                        button2b_value[i] = currentRandomString;
                        i++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Context.uIManager.UpdateAllPyramidaButtons();
    }
```

**2.Accept button(after click on this button, regenerate values again):**

```
public void OnAcceptButton()
{
    CheckIfPlayerSelectRightButton();
    selectedButton_value = null;
    SetUpPyramidButtonsValues();
}
```

**3.Check if seleceted value by player is correct:**

```
 if (answer_value.Contains(selectedButton_value))
    {
        //Check if choosen letter is in the secretary
        string[] character = new string[answer_value.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < answer_value.Length; i++)
        {
            character[i] = answer_value[i].ToString();
            if (character[i] == selectedButton_value)
            {
                AddItemToUsedLetters(selectedButton_value);
                skuska[i].enabled = true;
                //HERE ADD POINTS
                timeRemaining = 30f;
                timerIsRunning = true;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        timeRemaining = 30f;
        timerIsRunning = true;
    }
```

Comment: If this runs on the core game thread with no breath until that value happens. Theres almost no processing time left for the value to change so yes. Unity likes to crash at never ending loops

Comment: @BugFinder its not that case, because this runs only when player click on button :) Player must select one of letter choices and click to accept button.

Comment: Does it crash after you click the button?

Comment: @BugFinder yea, but not on the first click. Usually I can play maybe 2 or 3 minutes (5 or 6 clicks) and after that it crash

Comment: Show us the surrounding code. Is it called within the Unity event loop, who is the caller, etc.

Comment: @Bart see editted main post. I addded all code associated with this method :)

Comment: Whenever I get a uppity while loop I put it in a coruoutine that waits for my input so I can follow along loop by loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop will never be broken if the set of `fourPointsLetters` is not contained in the set of `usedLetters` and contained in the set of `button4_value`.

A way to solve your issue could be to completely avoid the while loop and use lists to prefilter the possible letters. As a bonus you will also get deterministic code with a fixed runtime.

```csharp
using System.Linq;
public List<string> fourPointsLetters, usedLetters, button4b_value;
/////////////

for (int i = 0; i < button4b_value.Count; i++)
{
    List<string> filteredStrings = fourPointsLetters.Except(usedLetters).Except(button4b_value).ToList();

    if (filteredStrings.Count == 0)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("No possible letters");
    }
    else
    {
        int index = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, filteredStrings.Count);
        button4b_value[i] = fourPointsLetters[index];
    }
}
```

This code also catches and warns you if there are no letters possible. You can change the handling according to your need.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I dont know that something like List.Except exist so your answer is very usefull and helpfull :)